# find two words with the same hash code in a large file - weird output

Tags: java, output, hashcode

I tried to find two words with the same hash code in `/usr/share/dict/words` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Trying keep `Map<Integer, HashSet<String>>`.

After reading word compute his hash code `h` and put the word in the set whose key is `h`.

Then iterate through all keys and print the sets whose size is > 1.

But I saw very weird output after running.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        HashSet<String> fileWords = new HashSet<>();
        Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> duplicats = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/usr/share/dict/words"));

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String word = scan.nextLine();
            int h = word.hashCode();
            fileWords.add(word);
            duplicats.put(new Integer(h), fileWords);
        }

        Set<Integer> keySet = duplicats.keySet();
        for (Integer key : keySet) {
            HashSet<String> value = duplicats.get(key);
            if (value.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println(key + " : " + value.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

***Output:***

```
21917608 : [repaying, Zubenelgenubi, treason, indignation, eyetooth, ....// a lot of words
```

It looks very weird. I can't figure out what is wrong?

**Update:**

I've found solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> duplicats = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/usr/share/dict/words"));

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        int h = word.hashCode();

        if (!duplicats.containsKey(h)) 
        {
            HashSet<String> newSet = new HashSet<>();
            newSet.add(word);
            duplicats.put(new Integer(h), newSet);
        } 
        else 
        {
            duplicats.get(h).add(word);
        }
    } /// rest the same
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: You say _in the set whose key is h_ but you're actually setting _all_ words found so far to each entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashSet<String> fileWords = new HashSet<>();
```

You instantiate just a single set and add all your words into it.

You must add logic which will:

1. check whether there is already a set under your current hashcode key;
2. if there is, just add the word to it;
3. if not, create a new set, add the word, and put it into the map.

The way you have it now, you are putting the same set under all the map keys.

Comment: I tried add this check into while `if (!duplicats.containsKey(h)) {
    HashSet<String> newSet = new HashSet<>();
    newSet.add(word);
    duplicats.put(new Integer(h), newSet);
   }` but this doesn't change situation to correct

Comment: OK, so debug on. I can't comment on code fragments which you have supposedly inserted into some other code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the purpose of your code, but in `duplicats` you are mapping each `hashCode` to the set of all `String`s in the file (`fileWords`).  And then displaying it.  The following code works as it could be expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Map<Integer,HashSet<String>> duplicats= new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>() ;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Downloads\\Software\\sourceforge.net\\souptonuts\\dictionary\\linuxwords.1\\linux.words"));

    while( scan.hasNext() ) {
        String word= scan.nextLine() ;
        int hc= new Integer( word.hashCode() ) ;
        HashSet<String> count= duplicats.get( hc ) ;
        if( count == null ) {
            count= new HashSet<String>() ;
            duplicats.put(hc, count ) ;
        }
        count.add( word );
    }

    int nonCollisionHashCodes= 0 ;
    int singleCollisionHashCodes= 0 ;
    int doubleCollisionHashCodes= 0 ;
    for(Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>> e : duplicats.entrySet() ) {
        if( e.getValue().size() <= 1 ) {
            nonCollisionHashCodes++;
        } else if( e.getValue().size() <= 2 ) {
            singleCollisionHashCodes++;
        } else if( e.getValue().size() <= 3 ) {
            doubleCollisionHashCodes++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue().size());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of non-collision hashCodes: "+ nonCollisionHashCodes );
    System.out.println("Number of single-collision hashCodes: "+ singleCollisionHashCodes );
    System.out.println("Number of double-collision hashCodes: "+ doubleCollisionHashCodes );
}
```

At least for my dictionary, output is:

```
Number of non-collision hashCodes: 626167
Number of single-collision hashCodes: 885
Number of double-collision hashCodes: 6
```

Note that there is no output for more than double-collision hashCodes.

To my taste, these stats are pretty good.  Try it with your dictionary and post your results.

Comment: @nazar_art  It would be very interesting if you can try this code with your dictionary.

Comment: I did this and here is results (this dictionary is typical at Unix systems):  `Number of non-collision hashCodes: 98917;
Number of single-collision hashCodes: 127;
Number of double-collision hashCodes: 0`